# R data.table filling in X previous rows with ID conditionally

Tags: r, data.table

I am working with a data set that resembles the following:

```
    Date         ID    diff
    2020-01-01   NA    NA
    2020-01-02   NA    NA
    2020-01-03   NA    NA
    2020-01-04   NA    NA
    2020-01-05   1     NA
    2020-01-06   NA    NA
    2020-01-07   NA    NA
    2020-01-08   NA    NA
    2020-01-09   2     4
    2020-01-10   NA    NA
    2020-01-11   NA    NA
    2020-01-12   NA    NA
    2020-01-13   NA    NA
    2020-01-14   NA    NA
    2020-01-15   3     6
    2020-01-16   NA    NA
    2020-01-17   NA    NA
    2020-01-18   NA    NA
    2020-01-19   4     4
    2020-01-20   NA    NA
```

I want to fill the ID value back the number of rows indicated in the diff column -1. So for example where the ID column==4, the diff column==4, so I want the previous 3 rows of ID (diff-1) to also be filled in as 4.

The result I'm looking for is as follows:

```
    Date         ID    diff
    2020-01-01   NA    NA
    2020-01-02   NA    NA
    2020-01-03   NA    NA
    2020-01-04   NA    NA
    2020-01-05   1     NA
    2020-01-06   2     NA
    2020-01-07   2     NA
    2020-01-08   2     NA
    2020-01-09   2     4
    2020-01-10   3     NA
    2020-01-11   3     NA
    2020-01-12   3     NA
    2020-01-13   3     NA
    2020-01-14   3     NA
    2020-01-15   3     6
    2020-01-16   4     NA
    2020-01-17   4     NA
    2020-01-18   4     NA
    2020-01-19   4     4
    2020-01-20   NA    NA
```

I tried doing this with a lag function, but couldn't figure out how to fill in the consecutive number of rows. Is there a better function/method to use for this?

Comment: what happens if this would result in overwriting a non-`NA` value?

Comment: The non-NA values should definitely be kept in tact- that's why the backfill must be diff-1, so the non-NA values are left untouched. I should probably have explained that the diff function is the difference in rows from the previous ID value.

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(data.table)
dat[, ID2 := fifelse(.N - seq_len(.N) < diff[.N], ID[.N], ID),
     by = rev(cumsum(!is.na(rev(diff))))]
dat
#           Date    ID  diff   ID2
#         <char> <int> <int> <int>
#  1: 2020-01-01    NA    NA    NA
#  2: 2020-01-02    NA    NA    NA
#  3: 2020-01-03    NA    NA    NA
#  4: 2020-01-04    NA    NA    NA
#  5: 2020-01-05     1    NA     1
#  6: 2020-01-06    NA    NA     2
#  7: 2020-01-07    NA    NA     2
#  8: 2020-01-08    NA    NA     2
#  9: 2020-01-09     2     4     2
# 10: 2020-01-10    NA    NA     3
# 11: 2020-01-11    NA    NA     3
# 12: 2020-01-12    NA    NA     3
# 13: 2020-01-13    NA    NA     3
# 14: 2020-01-14    NA    NA     3
# 15: 2020-01-15     3     6     3
# 16: 2020-01-16    NA    NA     4
# 17: 2020-01-17    NA    NA     4
# 18: 2020-01-18    NA    NA     4
# 19: 2020-01-19     4     4     4
# 20: 2020-01-20    NA    NA    NA
#           Date    ID  diff   ID2
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- setDT(structure(list(Date = c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-05", "2020-01-06", "2020-01-07", "2020-01-08", "2020-01-09", "2020-01-10", "2020-01-11", "2020-01-12", "2020-01-13", "2020-01-14", "2020-01-15", "2020-01-16", "2020-01-17", "2020-01-18", "2020-01-19", "2020-01-20"), ID = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA), diff = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA)), class = c("data.table",  "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L)))
```